# Create a separate ethernet network using a second router, using ISP Router for internet access?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking, dd-wrt

I have an ISP Router which is a cable modem+router. It has Wifi and 4 LAN ports. Wifi is used by phones, computers, etc to access the internet.

I have 2/3 separate computers (without Wifi), which I'd like to give access to the internet via this ISP Router, through ethernet cables... and to *also* create a little **separate** network <sup>see note</sup> limited only to these separate computers. I also have an old router (a Motorola WR850G which has [DD-WRT](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Flash_Your_Motorola_WR850G) firmware on it.).

Is it possible to attach my DD-WRT router with the ISP Router somehow to accomplish that? If so, how?

Thank you very much for your help.

**NOTE** *The ISP Router's DHCP currently assigns all devices IPs ranging from 192.168.0.20 to 192.168.0.200 I think, and IPv6 addresses also. So I am thinking may be to make the separate network really "separate", it should have a different range? I am a newbie at routers, etc, so would also appreciate some help there too.*

Comment: You should spend some time and learn how to setup and configure the DD-WRT router. Documentation is most likely available online. For starters you can connect the router to your ISP router using the WAN port. then connect computers to the other ports. This may or may not require some configuration by you on the DD-WRT router. But give it a try, hook it up, reboot everything and see if it works.

Comment: Hint: it will be a unbridged network, with its own separate subnet. In the bridging section you then attach it to a physical port. Beware, in alot of routers the physical port numbers are backwards compared to how the firmware numbers them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed to do that, for anyone who stumbles on to it:

1. Connected `ISP-Router` LAN port to `second-router` router's WAN port via ethernet cable
2. Connected `second-router` LAN ports with computers
3. On one connected computer, open in browser 192.168.1.1 > Setup > Router IP: `192.168.5.1` > Apply changes
4. Rebooted all routers and computers
5. All computers wired with `second-router` now have internet plus their own separate network.